# Create product using Oauth & curl

Tags: magento, oauth, restful-authentication

Im trying to create product using RESTful Api. Achieved this functionality using RESTCLIENT firefox addon but failed using script. I can able to list products But im not able to create product using script.  Getting access denied error. Can anyone help me?

Here is my script.

```
$url = 'http://magento.com/api/rest/products';
$method = 'POST';

# headers and data (this is API dependent, some uses XML)
$headers = array(
'Accept: application/json',
'Content-Type: application/json',
'oauth_signature_method : HMAC-SHA1', 
'oauth_nonce : ilJuravy9KVYm6R', 
'oauth_timestamp : 1363848967', 
'oauth_consumer_key : xxx',
'oauth_consumer_secret : yyy',
'oauth_token : zzz',
'oauth_token_secret : xyz',
'oauth_signature : 4admodOkAj2pKwhO5Tk6TEjc7Rg%3D',
'oauth_verifier: mrr1350pp0j8hiyv31kzxhko97hyyuwx',
'oauth_version : 1.0',
);
$data = json_encode(
array(
    'type_id'           => 'simple',
    'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
    'sku'               => 'simple' . uniqid(),
    'weight'            => 1,
    'status'            => 1,
    'visibility'        => 4,
    'name'              => 'Simple Product',
    'description'       => 'Simple Description',
    'short_description' => 'Simple Short Description',
    'price'             => 99.95,
    'tax_class_id'      => 0,
)
);

$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

switch($method) {
case 'GET':
break;
case 'POST':
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
break;
case 'PUT':
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
break;
case 'DELETE':
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
break;
}

echo $response = curl_exec($handle);
echo $code = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to generate 3 things mention below and other things are static like oauth_consumer_key,oauth_token etc.

1.timestmap
2.signature
3.nonce

i have generated all things see below code.

```
$nonce = substr(md5(uniqid('nonce_', true)),0,16);
$temprealm="http://magentohost/api/rest/products";
$realm=urlencode($temprealm);
$oauth_version="1.0";
$oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1";
$oauth_consumer_key="lro2hnoh3c8luvhcr49j6qgygmyvw7e3";
$oauth_access_token="xbqe4wnu3zv357gimpdnuejvcbtk51ni";
$oauth_method="GET";
$oauth_timestamp=time();
$algo="sha1";
$key="sb88hfdihyg25ipt1by559yzbj2m3861&s7uhaheu8nrx961oxg6uc3os4zgyc2tm"; //consumer secret & token secret //Both are used in generate signature
$data="oauth_consumer_key=".$oauth_consumer_key."&oauth_nonce=".$nonce."&oauth_signature_method=".$oauth_signature_method."&oauth_timestamp=".$oauth_timestamp."&oauth_token=".$oauth_access_token."&oauth_version=".$oauth_version;

$send_data=$oauth_method."&".$realm."&".urlencode($data);
$sign=hash_hmac($algo,$send_data,$key,1); // consumer key and token secrat used here
$fin_sign=base64_encode($sign);
$curl = curl_init();



curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Authorization : OAuth realm='.$realm.', oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_nonce="'.$nonce.'", oauth_timestamp="'.$oauth_timestamp.'", oauth_consumer_key='.$oauth_consumer_key.', oauth_token='.$oauth_access_token.', oauth_signature="'.$fin_sign.'"'));

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$temprealm);
$xml=curl_exec($curl);
```